# Where does Network Manager write connection settings for eth0?

Tags: network-manager

In Ubuntu I have configured network through network manager.

Every thing is working fine.My machine is pinging self machine as well as remote machine. but file `/etc/network/interfaces` doesn't contain eth0 details.

I also looked into file `/etc/networkmanager/networkmanager.conf` but there is no entry for eth0 details.

So where does the network manager write network details??

Answer (score 2):

Network Manager stores system-wide connection information in the `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/` directory, with one file for each named connection. For `eth0` it may have a default name such as `Wired connection 1`.

Comment: Can you tell me from where may i get BOOTPROTO information. Wired connection 1 doesn't contain BOOTPROTO information.

Comment: Trying to figure out what you mean in comments is difficult. As this isn't the question you asked at all, I suggest you ask a new question so others can help you clarify it.

Comment: @RobieBasak: Actually network script files also contain BOOTPROTO information in other distributions. I am looking for same and i thought that if i get network details then that information will also be there.

Comment: Best to ask for what you want exactly. Ask a question "How do I find BOOTPROTO information for eth0" for example.